# Limit of a complex function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

Can someone show me how to find the limit of a complex function?

Example:

```
z1 = 3 + 4*I

some_function[z] = z * z1
```

Set-up:

```
Limit[some_function[z],z->z1]
```

The result should be

> ```
> (4*I + 3)*z
> ```

but I get

> ```
> Limit[some_function[z], z -> 3 + 4 I]
> ```

What am I doing wrong? I tried to search in google and in the help files in the section about complex analysis.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can't use `_` in names. the `_` is used for patterns. Also your function definitions are not correct. Need to use delay assignment `:=`

May be this will work for you:

```
ClearAll[z, z1];
z1 = 3 + 4*I;
someFunction[z_] := z*z1;
Limit[someFunction[z], z -> z1]

  (*-7 + 24 I*)
```

see [DefiningFunctions.html](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html)   and [what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/)

Answer (score 1):

Taking a sample complex function as example with `z->1+i`

```
eq = z^2 - 2 z + 1;
```

Separating complex and Real part,

```
eqt = ComplexExpand[eq //. {z -> x + I y}]
```

> 1 - 2 x + x^2 - y^2 + I (-2 y + 2 x y)

Taking real part,

```
Cases[eqt, x_ /; FreeQ[x, I]] /. List -> Plus
```

> 1 - 2 x + x^2 - y^2
>   Calculating limit for real part as,

```
Limit[Limit[1 - 2 x + x^2 - y^2, x -> 1], y -> 1]
```

> -1

Taking Complex part,

```
Complement[eqt, 1 - 2 x + x^2 - y^2]
```

> I (-2 y + 2 x y)
>   Taking limit as,

```
Limit[Limit[(-2 y + 2 x y), x -> 1], y -> 1]
```

> 0

So, by theorems of Complex Analysis its limit is `-1`.
Use [Example 2.17 on this Page](http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/c2003/ComplexFunLimitMod.html)